# Facing issue on clicking Tenant rather all working fine for user and roles in AspBoilerPlate aspnet core with angular

Tags: angular, swagger-ui, asp.net-core-1.0, boilerplate, aspnetboilerplate

[image]

Facing issue "an internal error has occured " on clicking Tenant.

[image]

How can I fix this issue. Please help me.

Comment: How is this related to `swagger-ui`?

Comment: In Asp Boiler Plate website there is an option to create template project where 2 solutions are generated for core and angular.  When we successfully compile and run Core project the result webpage is Swagger-UI which is used by Angular-UI for request and response

Comment: https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Templates

Comment: couldn't see your embedded image... can you explain the problem in detail

Comment: Actually my http://localhost:5000/api/services/app/Tenant/GetAll is throwing error -  Response Body:{
  "result": null,
  "targetUrl": null,
  "success": false,
  "error": {
    "code": 0,
    "message": "An internal error occurred during your request!",
    "details": null,
    "validationErrors": null
  },
  "unAuthorizedRequest": false,
  "__abp": true
}................   Response Code:500. So please help me to solve my problem

Comment: What's in the error log?

Comment: Post the actual error, this is a wrapped error message so users don't see the details. Turn debugging on